# How to make file "db/file.c" be able to say #include "db/file.h" via Premake 5?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, premake

Googles LevelDB is a good library. Yet it has compilation files for linux only. It has some outdated Windows ports and instructions like [this one from Microsoft](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/LevelDB/blob/master/leveldbNative/WINDOWS). Instructions are outdated. Any way I want to be able to compile latest leveldb on windows and on linux having a single configuration file thus I am using premake to create configuration.

They use intresting includes stratagy. Having a [`db/file.cc`](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/db/version_set.cc) they refrence its includes:

```
#include "db/file.h"
```

I wonder how to make premake configure solution so that all files see themselfs in project root "/" even when they are in "/db/" folder. Or may be there are other ways to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the include files search path to the project root.

```
includedirs { "." }
```